# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - VueJS

Tags: cross-domain, vue.js, same-origin-policy

I'm developing a VueJS application which makes calls to an external API. When I do this:

```
this.$http.get(myAPIurl)
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

I get these 2 errors in chrome console.

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method"

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxxxx Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: What is server for your backend API- myAPIurl

Comment: @saurabh I'm using musixmatch API, so it's a third party server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to a different domain than your page is on, your browser will block it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is *[Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)*.

When you are using postman they are not restricted by this policy. Quoted from *[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)*:

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

To solve this, your external API server has to support cors request by setting following headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

### Edited

You can use format as `jsonp`, like it is being done in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/brian_jenney/pen/dGKmyX). [Here](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/35) is discussion on how to use `jsonp` with vue-resource, see sample code from this link:

```
this.$http.jsonp('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + this.hash + '/media/recent', {
    client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}, function(data){
    this.pictures = _map(data.data, this.transFormInstagramModelToLocalModel);
}, {
    'jsonp': 'callback'
});
```

You can find discussions [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/cors-and-vuejs) also helpful.